# GUPSHUP endpoint for user status?

Tags: whatsapp, gupshup, opt

I see in this documetation https://www.gupshup.io/docs/partner/#UsefulApis that exists, but when i try on postman for example the get "https://api.gupshup.io/sm/api/v2/userStatus" with the phone and apikey on header, i recevied error 404. However when i try to check the wallet with get "https://api.gupshup.io/sm/api/v2/wallet/balance" everything works fine.

Anyone knows if the endpoint is wrong or something?

With the two links only the wallet one works